# How to create an Enter button?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a chat bot. To increase the user friendliness, I need to let the user to press enter button to submit what he typed. 
I tried few thing. but did not worked.

used default button on the web page.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="Button1" Height="414px">
```

coded the enter button separatly

```
private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myBot.Read(this.txtInput.Text);
    this.txtInput.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

I need to do this on a ASP.Net web page.
please help.

Comment: Are you sure 'button1' is binded to 'btnEnter_click' event?

Comment: I'm not sure. how do I make it sure?

Comment: Check the value of OnClick attribute of the `<asp:Button />` tag of `Button1`. It should be set to `btnEnter_Click`

Answer (score 1):

What does the code for your button look like?

From what you have posted it should look something like this

`<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnEnter_Click" runat="server" />`

Comment: this is what I was talking about.